# Power Automate SharePoint Copy File action started failing

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Have a Power Automate flow which copies pages from one site to another which started failing this morning with the error:

Invalid number value.

A number field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again.

Checked for any changes in content types etc but nothing seems to have changed.

Created two new sites on a different tenancy with no additional content types or fields associated to the Site Pages folders. Created a simple copy file action. It failed in the same way.

[image: simple flow]

Is anyone else having this issue? Any ideas if not

Comment: We started seeing the same issue today.  Trying to find a workaround, but something must have changed in the back-end.

Comment: We've been progressing the call with Microsoft support today and they have identified the recent code release which caused the problem. The SharePoint team are looking at a fix but we have no time scales as yet.

Comment: This is now fixed. They pushed a change out last night. Happy days :)